# Executing thread only in one Android Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I have three java files in my Android project. Two are activities (`MainActivity` and `GeoActivity`) and one is a plain java file (`PostHttp` -> sends data to server via the HTTP POST)

I switch over to `GeoActivity` via a simple button on-click method. `GeoActivity` returns the co-ordinates of the current location in a TextView AND sends them to a remote server via the HTTP POST.
I have a `Handler.class` which executes sends the Post Message after a delay of 50s. Something like this below. The problem i have is that when i click the back button and switch over to `MainActivity` i can still see in LogCat the echoes receiving from the server that the data is still being sent. How can i stop that?

**GeoActivity.class**

```
public class GeoActivity extends Activity {
Location location;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....

if(location != null){
    mHandler.postDelayed(updateTask,0);
}
...
}
...
public Runnable updateTask = new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    mlocListener.onLocationChanged(location);
    //send coordinates with a delay of 50s
    new PostHttp(getUDID(),latitude,longitude).execute();
    mHandler.postDelayed(updateTask, 50000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try acting on the activity's life cycle.

For example:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Save the note's current draft, because the activity is stopping
    // and we want to be sure the current note progress isn't lost.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE, getCurrentNoteText());
    values.put(NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, getCurrentNoteTitle());

    getContentResolver().update(
            mUri,    // The URI for the note to update.
            values,  // The map of column names and new values to apply to them.
            null,    // No SELECT criteria are used.
            null     // No WHERE columns are used.
            );
}
```

This doesn't destroy the activity, it will reside in memory. However, you can always resume when needed.

Source:

[Stopping and Restarting Android Activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)